# Convert DTS ActiveX to Script Task in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, dts

I'm new to this forum and this is my first thread so I hope I am posting it in the right location.

I don't know any C# but I know some VB, I have migrated my DTS package to SSIS but I'm unable to get the ActiveX script working and decided to re-write it in a script task. I have 4 global varibles and they all have values already set in the Global variables menu. link to a picture: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0ilx.jpg). The ActiveX code is there so the user can just alter 2 vars when they switch server/database and it will still do the same on the tables there (all tables have to same name across all the servers and databases so that doesn't need to be adjusted) and it is automaticly run daily. This is the original ActiveX code:

```
Function Main()

Dim sEnvironm       
Dim sServer            
Dim sSourceFile     
Dim sSourcePath    
Dim sBackupPath  
Dim sErrorPath      
Dim sFileName        
Dim sUDLPath    

'*********************************************************
' Set vars 
' 
' First 2 are depending on the server and db
' FILL IN THE RIGHT VALUES
' 
'*********************************************************
sEnvironm = "MON_Datamart"
sServer =  "W0254"



' --- DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ---
' ---
sSourceFile  = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\DTS\SourceFiles\tbl_L47T1.txt"
sSourcePath = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\DTS\SourceFiles\"
sBackupPath  = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\DTS\BackupFiles\"
sErrorPath   = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\DTS\ErrorFiles\"
sFileName = "tbl_L47T1.txt"
sUDLPath = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\UDL\" & sEnvironm & ".udl"


FoundError = False

Set oPackage = DTSGlobalVariables.Parent

Set oConnection = oPackage.Connections("tbl_L47T1.txt")
oConnection.DataSource = sSourceFile

Set oConnection = oPackage.Connections("Datamart")
oConnection.UDLPath = sUDLPath 

Set oConnection = oPackage.Connections("Truncate")
oConnection.UDLPath = sUDLPath 

Set oTask = oPackage.Tasks("DTSTask_DTSDataPumpTask_1").CustomTask
oTask.SourceObjectName = sSourceFile
oTask.DestinationObjectName =  sEnvironm & ".dbo.stg_tbl_L47T1" 

DTSGlobalVariables("SourcePath").Value = sSourceFile
DTSGlobalVariables("BackupPath").Value = sBackupPath
DTSGlobalVariables("ErrorPath").Value = sErrorPath
DTSGlobalVariables("FileName").Value = sFileName   

Set oTask = Nothing
Set oConnection = Nothing
Set oPackage = Nothing

Main = DTSTaskExecResult_Success

End Function
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub Main()

        Dim sEnvironm As  String
        Dim sServer As String
        Dim sSourceFile As String
        Dim sSourcePath As String
        Dim sBackupPath As String
        Dim sErrorPath As String
        Dim sFileName As String
        Dim sUDLPath As String
        Dim FoundError As Boolean
        Dim oPackage As Object
        Dim oConnection As Object
        Dim oTask As Object
        Dim DTSGlobalVariables As Object



        '*********************************************************
        ' Set vars 
        ' 
        ' First 2 are depending on the server and db
        ' FILL IN THE RIGHT VALUES
        ' 
        '*********************************************************
        sEnvironm = "MON_Datamart"
sServer =  "W0254"



' --- DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ---
' ---
sSourceFile  = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\DTS\SourceFiles\tbl_L47T1.txt"
sSourcePath = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\DTS\SourceFiles\"
sBackupPath  = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\DTS\BackupFiles\"
sErrorPath   = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\DTS\ErrorFiles\"
sFileName = "tbl_L47T1.txt"
sUDLPath = "\\" & sServer & "\Data_sql\" & sEnvironm & "\UDL\" & sEnvironm & ".udl"

FoundError = False

oPackage = Dts.Variables("User::VariableName").Value

oConnection = oPackage.Connections("tbl_L47T1.txt")
oConnection.DataSource = sSourceFile

oConnection = oPackage.Connections("Datamart")
oConnection.UDLPath = sUDLPath 

oConnection = oPackage.Connections("Truncate")
oConnection.UDLPath = sUDLPath 

oTask = oPackage.Tasks("DTSTask_DTSDataPumpTask_1").CustomTask
oTask.SourceObjectName = sSourceFile
oTask.DestinationObjectName =  sEnvironm & ".dbo.stg_tbl_L47T1" 

DTSGlobalVariables("SourcePath").Value = sSourceFile
DTSGlobalVariables("BackupPath").Value = sBackupPath
DTSGlobalVariables("ErrorPath").Value = sErrorPath
DTSGlobalVariables("FileName").Value = sFileName   

oTask = Nothing
oConnection = Nothing
oPackage = Nothing

Main = DTSTaskExecResult_Success
    End Sub
```

If I debug this I get a lot of errors and I have no clue on how to fix them...

error:

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Het doel van een aanroep heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0010009): The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.

   bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSVariables100.get_Item(Object Index)
   bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
   bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   bij ST_f32fc12b60f34bebbbdfc0c5e5b40a96.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
   bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bij System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   bij System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Could someone please help me convert this further? I'm stuck and don't know how to fix my errors...

Thanks in advance!

- Michael

Comment: I suggest you get rid of your script altogether and instead use _package configurations_ to set the source server. Then you just edit an XML file, not the actual package.

Comment: Hello Nick and thank you for commenting on my problem! With package configurations do you mean the connection I had to make to the DB in the package or what do you mean by that? Also, I have never even heard of an XML file, how could I make this function so that It can be used like the script to run the package automatic on a daily basis?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are your packages running on? 2012 or an earlier version? please tag it. If you do some research on SSIS _file_ package configurations all will be explained. Why don't you do some reading from here, the first thing that came up in a search: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx then ask some specific questions.

Comment: I added a tag for the version I'm using (2008 enterprise). I'll get back to you once I have some more specific questions but just to clearify; it is possible to use a XML file to do a automatic daily runtime of the package and also make it so that if I change the data source it changes all the paths in all the packages? The tables used by the packages all have the same name across all the servers and Databases so if the server and/or DB would be changed it should all work the same way but on a different server without changing anything else, that is possible with XML?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible with XML configurations. The automatic daily part is normally achieved by using a SQL Agent job

Comment: I figured out how to make variables change with the XML so that I don't need to do that inside BIDS every time, very helpfull! How do I make it do the same with the server and database connection in the data source?

Comment: I think this explains it pretty well. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/xml-configuration-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: I will be making a seperate XML file for each table that needs to be updated from my .txt file (this I already set up with a control flow) This is because each txt and it's linked table in the DB have different names so I just make a XML for each package to change the vars. When this is done I will just copy ALL the packages and XML files and all I need to do is change the server and database connection in EACH XML file but I just need to know HOW I make my XML file able to change the connection for the package it is linked to. I just need a piece of code to change the connection from the XML.

Comment: I found this website: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_2005_making_ssis_packages_portable.htm they seem to explain what I am looking for but (maybe it's just me) I can't understand what the hell he is talking about and with all the different code examples he provides I have no idea wich one I should use and what in it I should actually change...

Comment: Forget about writing code. There is no code. Go to this link https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/xml-configuration-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/ and follow the instructions from "Setting Up Your XML Configuration File". At "Select Properties to Export", go through and pick all of the items that you want to change, i.e. all of the connection managers to the database and to the files. When you click FINISH in the wizard, it has created the XML file for you. Get that far and post back.

Comment: Once you have done this, everytime you package runs it goes and looks in the XML file (at the path you specified) and applies things it finds in there. So in that wizard if you saved the 'file path' property in there, and you need this path to change, you change the XML file and it will apply to the package, Normally you have this exact same path set up on different servers with different values so depending on the server it's running on, the values change. You can also these values directly from within a SQL Agent job if that helps.

Comment: Like I said I already read that and did it. I am able to change all the variables but I need to change the connection. that link talks about adding the Servername to the XML. This is of 0 use to me. I looked further on the internet and found out that I need to select the ConnectionString property. I did this but when I change the connection string in the XML and I execute the SSIS package I get a error. I think you are misunderstanding me. In the connection manager I want to add a NEW connection from the XML file that was not inside the manager before I execute the package. error:

Comment: TITLE: Package Validation Error
------------------------------

Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Package1: The connection "BRECHTPROESMANS\SQL2008R2.MON_Datamart" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Comment: That is the error I get if I try to change the server the package is currently using. So in short: I take the ConnectionString from the "BRECHTPROESMANS" server and the "MON_Datamart" database. This connection is already inside the connection manager and the package works 100% on this server and DB BUT If I change the connectionstring to server "BRECHTPROESMANS\SQL2008R2" and database "MON_Datamart" Then I get the above error. It isn't supposed to "find" the connection it is supposed to CREATE the connection to that new server and database and run the package there.

Comment: However if I manually add a OLE DB connection in the connection manager the package runs fine like it should on the new server and DB. I just need the XML file to add a new OLE DB connection.

Comment: Your existing DTS ActiveX script alters _existing_ connections. Your existing SSIS data flows use _existing_ connections. I don't understand why you need to create a new connection. You should alter the properties of the existing connection (just like your ActiveX script does) that your existing data flow is using. The name of the connection manager (that you see at the bottom) is a logical name and does not reflect what the connection actually is. In fact you should rename these straight away to the logical name of the 'system' not the name of the server.

Comment: The config 'finds' the existing connection manager and changes the connection string (or server or database or path to a file) in it based on what is in the config file. Then existing dataflows use that same connection manager and connect based on the connection string, which might have been previously changed by a config (or by a command line switch or by a SQL Agent job)

Comment: "The connection "BRECHTPROESMANS\SQL2008R2.MON_Datamart" is not found" means that something (possibly a config) tried to reference a connection manager with a logical name "BRECHTPROESMANS\SQL2008R2.MON_Datamart" but it couldn't find it. This is a bad name for a connection manager. You should rename it to what this system is, not it's connection info.

Comment: Omg I'm stupid.... I was editing the Object name ASWELL as the name of the server and DB so my object didn't exist.... I tought the name of the connection manager represented the actual connection it did. It's working now! Thank you so much for your help! <3

Comment: Could you enter your comment as an answer so I can flag this as solved so It might help other people aswell.

Comment: not stupid at all.... just climbing the learning curve!! good luck with everything. Those connection manager names are very misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you get rid of your script altogether and instead use package configurations to set the source server. Then you just edit an XML file, not the actual package.

Here's a good guide: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/xml-configuration-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Just something to remember: don't edit the logical name of connection manager, instead edit the connection string inside it.

I suggest you rename your connection managers to what they really are (i.e. "customersystem" if extracting customers from a customer system) rather than what server they are pointing at (MySQLServerHost\SQLExpress.DBName), as the actual connection details will change from your configurations.